# Is it legitimate to award a bounty to a very good answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

My understanding is bounties are used to attract more viewers for a possible difficult or an urgent question.

My question is: what if I already see somebody is answering my question and putting extra effort to provide very clean and working code, and I'm so happy with the answer?

In this case I really want to reward that person with more than just an up-vote.

Is it legitimate that I put a bounty on my question (which already has a solid answer) and then award it to that person?

Comment: I've done this a few times. bounty away!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is legitimate.

It is one way to reward a great answer beyond upvoting and accepts.

For further info check the FAQ entry *[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)*

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I actually went through the "How does the bounty system work? but could not find that specific  scenario that I mentioned.

Comment: @SNash From the FAQ entry: "**Can I award a bounty to an old answer?** Yes, you can award your bounty to any answer on the question. This makes it possible for users to reward particularly good answers with more rep than a standard upvote would provide.". And there's event a specific bounty reason for it called "Reward existing answer".

Comment: This is very good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at it is that if you are very interested in the responses that may come from the question, it could be seen that you are making an investment in a great and informative answer to that particular question.

Comment: Agreed. Today someone clearly answered my question and his answer is a great time saver for me. I just wanted to make sure awarding bouties to an existing answer is legitimate.